# Electron-forge trying to restart with nodemon - works but fails to load preload

Tags: nodemon, electron-forge

So electron-forge restarts React (renderer) but not the main process (electron app itself). To get around constantly manually restarting and restarting on file changes I tried to setup nodemon. It works but when nodemon starts or restarts the app the preload doesn't load up.

Here's my nodemon.json

```
{
  "watch": ["src/back/"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "delay": "500",
  "exec": "npm run start"
}
```

Here's my package.json, excluding the dependencies.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "productName": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": ".webpack/main",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx .",
    "dev": "nodemon"
  },
... deps
```

I've tried to configure nodemon in package.json and inline with the command restarts files in the **back** folder but won't load the preload either way.

I know I can restart by typing **rs** in the terminal to get a quick restart. This isn't stopping me from coding, but it's such an annoying problem that I want to figure out why it's doing this. So any help would be appreciated.

This is the error I get

```
VM157 renderer_init:2 Unable to load preload script: C:\Users\potato\fry\.webpack\renderer\main_window\preload.js
```

**Below you can find my project structure**

[image: project structure]

**Extra that might matter**

- I'm using Windows 11
- I've used both Bash terminal and CMD
- This template was taken from electron-forge's official docs [here](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template)
- Webpack was taken from their docs [here](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack)